# Showing fields from parent tables in Django Admin screens

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to show a field in the admin screen from a model that is linked to from another model.

I have models like so:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)

class Building(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)    
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)  

class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)    
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building)
```

And admin models like this:

```
class BuildingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'location') 

class RoomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'building')
```

How can I show in the admin list for the Room model 3 columns, room name, building name and location name?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "the admin screen"? The changelist? The change form?

Comment: the lists, so the columns for the list of entries for the room model will be Room, Building, Location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom method in admin and use it in `list_display`.

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('upper_case_name',)

    def upper_case_name(self, obj):
      return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()
    upper_case_name.short_description = 'Name'
```

This way you can display whatever you want in list_display. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) you have full docs.

Comment: True, but the third column is not a field in the model in this case, it is a field in the model that this model links to via a foreign key.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it will be possible. Try it out.

Comment: I tried this before asking the question:  

    class RoomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display = ('name', 'building', 'building.location')

Comment: You should instead try: ` list_display = ('name', 'building', 'building__location')`

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result:

RoomAdmin.list_display[2], 'building__location' is not a callable or an attribute of 'RoomAdmin' or found in the model 'Room'.

Comment: Oh, so it seems it's not supported. I didn't know that. Well, you just need to write your own method than that will retrieve the value from foreign key.